# C #include sth dependency confused

Tags: c

I have the following code in `main.c`

```
#include "config.h"
#include "util.h"
```

and in `config.h`

```
#include "util.h"
```

and there is a normal function in `util.h`

as I have include the util.h twice, I expect it should be wrong

but unfortunately, it goes damn well when I type: `gcc main.c config.c util.c`

why is this right?

Comment: As an aside: Many things like declaring the same function or defining the same macro twice aren't a problem, but e.g. redeclaring a `typedef` is not allowed. So header guards are not always necessary (just to explain why you didn't get an error, not to suggest omitting header guards, of course).

Comment: got you point, one more question, Is it necessary to give each #INCLUDE a header guard?

Comment: Do you mean guarding the `#include` directive itself? Look at the answers again, the _header files_ are guarded (so you don't have to care when `#include`ing them). And usually this is done with all header files; exceptions are, where multiple includes are desired for some reason. E.g. `<assert.h>` is such a header or if you use the preprocessor for templating.

Comment: "the header files are guarded"  you mean the `#include` is guarded by default so there's no need for me to write `ifndef` ?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't get your question. You usually have guards with `#ifndef` in every header and `#include`s without any guards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should not cause an error

if you have next files:

inc.h, inc1.h and inc.h includes inc1.h and inc1.h includes inc.h, then it cause of error

in the header files made following agreement:

```
        #ifndef HEADER_NAME_H
        #defiene HEADER_NAME_H
        //body of header file
        #endif /*HEADER_NAME_H*/
```

where HEADER_NAME_H is "header_name.h" filename

Answer (score 1):

C headers usually have *header guards* that prevent them to be included multiple times. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>  // multiple inclusion of stdio.h, that's fine
```

A header guard is placed at the top of the header:

```
 #ifndef MYHEADER_H
 #define MYHEADER_H

 // content of the header file

 #endif MYHEADER_H
```

Comment: Is it necessary to give each #INCLUDE a header guard?